# Can I make one object have the same order as another object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object

I know that the title of this question already doesn't make sense because objects are unordered by their nature. BUT, I think if you take a look at this screen shot that's linked here, it'll make more sense.

[Picture of the two objects in my console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dh2H.png)

Here is what's happening. I am creating an object called $scope.gameConfigs, which is itself created from data I receive from a server call (a provisions object). This $scope.gameConfigs creates a group of dropdown menus.

Basically what I'm trying to do is make the dropdown menus display previously saved data IF the data exists. When saved data exists, the server returns an object that has all the saved data. This data is ordered numerically. My problem is, this saved data is not always ordered the same as the data in the $scope.gameConfigs I create, which results in blank fields appearing in my dropdowns.

If you look at the screenshot I linked to, you can see that the keys in $scope.gameConfigs (the object with line 30 written next to it) are Map, Server, and Mode.

The second object, which is the saved data returned from the server, is a group of objects that each have a name property (which is the name of the dropdown menu). If you take a look at that, the order is Server, Map, and Mode.

My question is, how can I make the Saved Data object copy the order of my $scope.gameConfigs object? Is that even possible? If not, what would be the best way to proceed?

Here is the HTML and the controller I have for my page/controller, too, if that helps at all:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="GamePreferenceCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(name, section) in gameConfigs">
        <label ng-bind="name"></label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="formData.settings[$index].value" ng-change="dropdownItemClicked(name, formData.settings[$index].value)">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled">---Please Select Option---</option>
            <option ng-repeat="item in section" value="{{item.value}}" ng-bind="item.value"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-include="gametemp"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
        <div class="text-center col-md-12 padding-15">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="saveGameSetting()" formnovalidate translate>
                <i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin' ng-if="showBusy"></i>&nbsp;Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the controller:

```
  function GamePreferenceCtrl($scope, $filter, Tournament, Notification) {
    $scope.$parent.child.game = $scope;
    $scope.selectedItems = [];
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.loadConfig = function () {
      Tournament.loadGameConfig($scope.id).then(function (response) {
        $scope.gameConfigs = {};

        if (response.data.tournamentPrefs) {
          _.each(response.data.tournamentPrefs, function (val) {
            if ($scope.formData.settings === undefined) {
              $scope.formData.settings = [];
            }
            $scope.formData.settings.push({section: val.name, value: val.value});
          });
          $scope.formData = {};
        };

        $scope.dropdownItemClicked = function(name, value) {
          if($scope.formData.settings === undefined) {
              $scope.formData.settings = {};
              $scope.formData.settings[name] = value;
          } else {
            console.log('inside else');
              $scope.formData.settings[name] = value;
          }

        };

        _.each(response.data.provisions, function (val) {
            if ($scope.gameConfigs[val.section] === undefined) {
              $scope.gameConfigs[val.section] = [];
            }
            $scope.gameConfigs[val.section].push({name: val.key, value: val.value});
        });
      });
    };
```

I know this is a long read, and I truly appreciate anyone who might be able to help me out with this. Thank you!

Comment: Like you said, objects are unordered. There's no guarantee about what order the keys will be displayed. At best, you could get the keys of an object (`Object.keys(obj)`) then sort them and finally print out each value for each key. But you can't make Chrome display the object keys in a certain order. You could also write a `toString` function and call that.

Comment: You could use an ES6 `Map`.

Comment: You should simplify problems. I'm pretty sure your question could be summarized in two lines and without a code sample, and it would be interesting enough anyway ;D

Comment: I think you might be working on the same platform idea that I am. I want to send you a message but there is no such thing on SO. I want to collaborate but this comment will be marked as spam in probably two minutes.. contact me at felipe d mullen at g. ma. i.l if you have any interest

Answer (score 0):

You may do like

```js
var o = {z:1, f:2, a:7}
    p = Object.assign({},o),
    q = Object.assign(o)
console.log(o, p, o === p);
console.log(o, q, o === q);
```